# adding custom tag to order in shopify based on a checkbox in product

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I made an html checkbox in my product template, now i need to add it to order whether it's checked or not(sorry i don't know liquid and search a-lot about it)
any help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Is the checkbox related to the product itself? If so then the [line item properties](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/line_item#line_item-properties) would be the best option. There is a great walkthrough on the [Shopify Forums](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Product-pages-Get-customization-information-for-products/td-p/616503) for this.

This property will then show up along with the product in the Order page of the Admin.

Comment: Thanks for the links. The product is a bundle of two products, so with the check box i want to give customer to ability to chose if they want both product ship together or if they don't mind to get products separately! my goal is if they checked the checkbox to get both at the same shipment add specific tag or even change the product title to make it easier in orders to recognise.